# Cordova - Error code 1 for command | Command failed for

Tags: android, node.js, git, cordova

I'm new on cordova, so if my question is not relevant, forgive me.
i have a cordova project in my Windows 7 x64 machine.
Yesterday i was build my cordova app via `cordova build android --release`.
But i need to add new plugin `cordova-plugin-zip` to update my cordova project. 
What i did to add this plugin to my cordova app;

- I installed a git application to my win7 x64 env.
- `npm install -g git` i wrote this command on cmd.
- I Opened Windows Environment Variables/Path Window and added `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`
- add plugin via this command `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git`
- then added other plugin `cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip.git`
  **(Everything fine till this step)**
- Then i run on cmd `cordova build android --release`

Unfourtunately it throws following error;

> BUILD FAILED C:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following
>   error occurred while execu ting this line:
>   C:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the
>   compiler error o utput for details.
>
> Total time: 7 seconds
>
> C:\hascevher\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,release,-f,C:\hascevher\platf
>   orms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with
>   exit code 1
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Hddn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
>   dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

When i try to create a new helloworld cordova project and adding android platform then from cmd `cordova build android` it creates sample app?

So what is wrong with my other application?

### Any help greatly appricated.

> - OS: Windows 7 x64
> - Cordova v 5.1.1
> - Ant version 1.9.4

Plugins On Cordova Project:

> - cordova-plugin-file
> - cordova-plugin-zip
> - org.apache.cordova.console
> - org.apache.cordova.device
> - org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Full Windows Environment Variables/Path:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;%C_EM64T_REDIST11%bin\Intel64;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;C:\cordova\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\android\sdk\tools;C:\android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\cmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer myself; and if someone will face same issue, i hope my solution will work for them as well.

- Downgrade NodeJs to 0.10.36
- Upgrade Android SDK 22

Answer (score 42):

I removed android platforms and installed again then worked. I wrote these lines in command window:

**cordova platform remove android** 
then
**cordova platform add android**

Comment: this is the fastest and easiest and simplest way for solve that

Answer (score 6):

Delete platforms/android folder and try to rebuild. That helped me a lot.

(Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova)

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer in response to Asker's "what is wrong with my other application?"

Comment: Though this doesn't answer the question of "what's happening and why?" this did resolve the issue for me - and since it's the top rated question in Google at the minute, people will still find it helpful. Make sure you take a backup of the platforms/android folder before taking this action though.

Comment: I tried this but still getting error with : `MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. (TaskId:10) Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:10)` Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Delete all the apk files from **platfroms >> android >> build >> generated >> outputs >> apk** 
 and run command **cordova run android**

Comment: "platfroms >> android >> app >> build  >> outputs >> apk" for the new versions of Cordova and Android

Answer (score 4):

I have had this problem several times and it can be usually resolved with a clean and rebuild as answered by many before me. But this time this would not fix it.

I use my cordova app to build 2 seperate apps that share majority of the same codebase and it drives off the config.xml. I could not build in end up because i had a space in my id.

```
com.company AppName
```

instead of:

```
com.company.AppName
```

If anyone is in there config as regular as me. This could be your problem, I also have 3 versions of each app. Live / Demo / Test - These all have different ids.

```
com.company.AppName.Test
```

Easy mistake to make, but even easier to overlook. Spent loads of time rebuilding, checking plugins, versioning etc. Where I should have checked my config. **First Stop Next Time!**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error code but different issue

`Error: /Users/danieloram/desktop/CordovaProject/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

To resolve this issue I opened the Android SDK Manager, uninstalled the latest Android SDK build-tools that I had (24.0.3) and installed version 23.0.3 of the build-tools.

My cordova app then proceeded to build successfully for android.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the file size restriction which was put on proxy server. Zip file of gradle was not able to download due this restriction. I was getting 401 error while downloading gradle zip file. If you are getting 401 or 403 error in log, make sure you are  able to download those files manually.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem. Problem lies in required version not installed.
Hack is simple Goto Platforms>platforms.json
Edit platforms.json in front of android modify the version to the one which is installed on system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and I've found that the first thing to do is look in the build output.

I found this error reported there:

> Reading build config file: \build.json... SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token

The solution for that was to [remove the bom from the build.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512740/150342)

Then I hit a second problem - with this message in the build output:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.   * What went wrong:   A
>   problem was found with the configuration of task ':packageRelease'.
>
> File 'C:\Users\Colin\etc' specified for property
>   'signingConfig.storeFile' is not a file.

Easily solved by putting the correct filename into the keystore property