# Changes disappearing when building Cordova app for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-cli, cordova-ios

I'm an absolute beginner with Cordova and was following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cordova/cordova_first_application.htm) tutorial when I started experiencing my problem.

The tutorial is more aimed at building the project for android but I applied the same steps to create an ios build on my mac.
`danieloram CordovaProject $ cordova run ios`

the default project builds and runs fine but whenever I edit either the index.html or cordova.js files in the ios directory of the platforms folder and run the above command (or `cordova build ios`), all my changes revert back to the default code.. This behaviour isn't mentioned anywhere that I can see in the linked tutorial.

*Am I missing something really obvious?*

I haven't been able to find anything online about any other users experiencing this issue.. so I'm inclined to think it is trivial.

Comment: Can you try editing using Xcode and see using Xcode build instead of cordova build ? Did you try that out ?

Comment: Running the app in Xcode the files my code stays :D but the default cordova app screen shows no matter what changes I make..

However, looking through a folder called 'Staging' I found an index.html file there and when I edited that the app changed! 

Do I need to change a config file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I found my answer, and a quick one at that.

The tutorial did not explicitly state which index.html file I was to edit so I naturally assumed it was the file nested inside the platforms/ios directory.

These file however should not be edited as they are overwritten using the outermost index.html file in the myapp/www/ folder.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089647/cordova-error-code-1-for-command-command-failed-for/39959098#39959098) sums it up perfectly with more detail.