# Cordova: Error in adding android platform

Tags: android, cordova

I tried to add android platform but got an error. I don't know what it is.

```
Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0
Installing "cordova-plugin-battery-status" for android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\MariaLigayahin\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Unzipping C:\Users\MariaLigayahin\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\MariaLigayahin\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    ... 3 more
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-battery-status':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\MariaLigayahin\Desktop\android_app\Helloworld\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Already tried removing and then adding again. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check the following issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39959098/2765346

Comment: Remove the plugin "cordova-plugin-battery-status". cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-battery-status then try adding platform.