# cordova requirements android target not installed cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:

Tags: android, apk

C:\Users\GINOM HANGSHING\hello>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHAJy.png)

Comment: The one that worked for me is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35034956

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your android platform by

C:\Users\GINOM HANGSHING\hello>**cordova platform update android --save**

Answer (score 0):

Add System variable, Path. Add "\tools" directory (in addition of "\platform-tools") of your Android SDK folder. There "android.bat" is located.

Restart any open terminals.

How to check Android SDK folder: [Android SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176594/android-sdk-location)

If you do not find a \tools folder in your Android SDK folder, you can either try reinstalling your Android SDK or downloading and extracting the tools without the IDE from the links below (Be sure to have read and agreed with the terms of service before downloading any of the command line tools)

Windows no installer: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip

MacOSX: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip

Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue on my machine.
(Deepin 20 community)

After updating my android platform by running the following commands:
`cordova platform rm android`
and
`cordova platform add android`

I configured my environment variables and path as follows:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="path-to-android-studio/Sdk"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_301/"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools"   
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator"
```

That solved the problem