# angular not loading in android deployment

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got this error [Cordova - Error code 1 for command | Command failed for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089647/cordova-error-code-1-for-command-command-failed-for)

so I followed one answer from there, I removed the Android platform then installed it again, now it's working on the device but angular is not loaded (it works fine in Chrome) any suggestion? still, have the old project, so even an answer on the first problem would be great

Comment: where did you bootstrapped ur angular app ? in deviceready function ?

Comment: In the html-> head, It worked just fine at the beginning until I had to remove and add again android

Comment: can you post your code HTML and js where u bootstrapped angular?

Comment: [link to plnkr,thanks](http://plnkr.co/edit/8Mw7iNukHMe75e6b2u8A?p=preview)